# Is it possible to set a directory where your script's output would go?

Tags: linux, scripting

I'm trying to manipulate some scripts. Is there a way to make my script's output go to a specific directory when executed?

This is what my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%H:%M:%s")
filename="cpuusage-OUT.$NOW.txt"

(
iostat -c | awk '{print$2,$4,$5}' | awk 'NR>1' | column -t
) > $filename
```

My plan is to put the output of this script to a file. Is it possible for me to somehow put the directory in this very script? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean `./script.sh >/path/to/output.txt`?

Comment: Or `./script.sh > /path/to/output.txt 2>&1` (if you want also to capture `stderr`)?

Comment: I'm not sure, am I supposed to create a new script containing **./script.sh >/path/to/output.txt or ./script.sh > /path/to/output.txt 2>&1**?

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect the standard output and input of the script.

You can redirect STDOUT with this `script > /var/log/output.log`
You can redirect STDERR with this `script 2> /var/log/output.err.log`
You can redirect BOTH with this `script 1> /var/log/output.log 2> /var/log/output.err.log`
OR `script > /var/log/output.log 2>&1` (The 2>&1 pipes STDERR to STDIN)

You can change /var/log/output.log to whatever you want.

Here's the documentation on it: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html